# How to give a specific context to a JavaScript function without invoking it right away

Tags: javascript, oop, closures

I'd like to create an object with some hidden (using closures) variables, and methods that utilize those hidden variables. I don't however want to recreate those methods for each instantiation. I'd like to have them in memory once. I'm using plain functions to instantiate objects.

Here's some code:

```
function Mario () {
  var mario = {}; // create the obj
  mario.name = "Mario"; // create a property on it
  mario.hp = (function () { // set up a closure
    var currentHp = Mario.baseHp * 100; // create a "hidden" variable
    return function (value) { // return the hp function that utilizes the hidden currentHp variable
      if (!!value) {
        return currentHp = ((currentHp * Mario.baseHp) + value);
      }
      return currentHp * Mario.baseHp;
    };
  }());
  return mario; // send along the newly created object
}
Mario.baseHp = 1;

var mario = Mario();
log(mario);
log(mario.hp());
log(mario.hp(-20));
log(mario.hp());
```

The problem here is that every time I create another "mario" object, I've created the hp function again in memory. Here's my attempt at a solution so far:

```
function Mario () {
  var mario = {}; // create the obj
  mario.name = "Mario"; // create a property on it
  mario.hp = (function () { // set up a closure
    var currentHp = Mario.baseHp * 100; // create a "hidden" variable
    return Mario.hp; // reference the hp function below..... but the context is wrong, it needs access to currentHp variable.
  }());
  return mario; // send along the newly created object.
}
Mario.baseHp = 1;
Mario.hp = function (value) { // Create the hp function once in memory
  if (!!value) {
    return currentHp = ((currentHp * Mario.baseHp) + value);
  }
  return currentHp * Mario.baseHp;
};
var mario = Mario();
log(mario);
log(mario.hp());
log(mario.hp(-20));
log(mario.hp());
```

But obviously the context of Mario.hp is wrong. I'm thinking there might be a way to use call or apply that would resolve this. Any help would rock!

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do, but [you may find this interesting.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)

Comment: Wow that's convoluted. Can you come up with a *minimalist* example demonstrating the question?

Comment: @Pointy Thanks! I've come across bind before, but it makes much more sense to me now.

Answer (score 3):

The usual solution is to use prototype and new :

```
function Mario () {
  this.name = "Mario"; // create a property on it
  this.baseHP = 33;
}
Mario.prototype.hp = function () { 
    var currentHP = this.baseHp * 100;
    ...
};

var mario = new Mario();
log(mario);
log(mario.hp());
log(mario.hp(-20));
log(mario.hp());
```

This creates what is usually called a class `Mario`. Using `new Mario()` create instances of this classe, all of them using the same function `hp` (`this` in the function refer to the instance).

EDIT

If you want to store the `currentHP` variable and the `hp` function to return it, simply do this :

```
function Mario () {
  this.name = "Mario"; // create a property on it
  this.baseHP = 33;
  this.currentHP = this.baseHp * 100;
}
Mario.prototype.hp = function () { 
    return this.currentHP;
};

var mario = new Mario();
log(mario);
log(mario.hp());
```

Comment: If you have `currentHP` inside a closure in the prototype, it will be the same value for all instances. I don't think that's what OP wants.

Comment: There is no [closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Closures) in my code. currentHP is dynamically computed each time hp is called using the value of baseHP of the instance.

Comment: Your previous edit had `Mario.prototype.hp = (function () { ...` as though there were a closed-over function inside it. I was referring to that.

Comment: The opening parenthesis was just a typo : a parenthesis I forgot to remove after copy-paste.

Comment: @dystroy Each time you call the hp function in your example it will "reset Mario's HP." I'm interested in storing currentHp as a private variable, and making it only accessible by the hp function. currentHp would need to persist beyond a single call of the hp function.

Comment: OK, I see what you mean. You want the hp function to be an accessor. See edit.

Comment: Yes, correct, sir. I implemented it with the new (well, not so new anymore) getters and setters in ECMAScript 5 as well. I also tested performance on jsperf for those and other techniques and I've arrived at the implementation above because it has great performance (best on almost all browsers) it's compatible everywhere, and it's not terribly unreadable.

Comment: You have some minor spelling errors: baseHP vs baseHp. Also the implementation in your edit sets this.currentHp to a number, so if you were to change baseHp and the call hp you would not get a new value, you'd just get the number 3300.

Answer (score 1):

```
var Mario = (function() {
  var name = "Mario"; 
  var hp = function (value) { 
      var currentHp = baseHp * 100; 
      if (!value) {
          return currentHp = ((currentHp * Enemy.baseHp) + value);
      }
      return currentHp * Enemy.baseHp;
  }
  return {
        name:name,
        hp:hp
  }
})();
console.log(Mario);
console.log(Mario.hp());
console.log(Mario.hp(-20));
console.log(Mario.hp());
```

I make no claim as to the validity of the rest of what you're doing, since there seem to be a lot of variable shown but not accounted for, but your enclosure seems to be in the wrong place.

Comment: `var function (value) {` Is this a typo? Looks like that line (and the matching `};` below) shouldn't be there. Or perhaps `var` should be `return` and the enclosing function should be run immediately.

Comment: @JustinMorgan you're absolutely right. I must have missed that trying to clean up the OP code.

Comment: Same challenge as dystory's answer. The hp function resets the value of currentHp everytime hp is called. I need currentHp to persist. I'm essentially trying to implement hp as an accessor.

Comment: Okay this is helpful too, there's an interesting bit there about the placement of the closure.

Answer (score 1):

I think all this discussion of prototypes is overkill, and not really all that helpful to your situation. You don't really need a prototype here, since all your instances of `Mario` are going to have their own value for `currentHp`. Likewise, you don't need to make `Mario` a true constructor and worry about having to remember the `new` keyword (although you can if you want).

As far as I can tell, everything you're trying to do can be handled by closures, with the added bonus of keeping your private members (like `baseHP` and your logic for calculating HP) truly private. Try this:

```
var Mario = (function () {
    //"private" variable encapsulated by the closure
    var baseHp = 1;

    //"private" method for calculating HP given an instance's current HP
    var getHp = function (currentHp, value) {
        return currentHp * Enemy.baseHp + (value || 0);
    };

    //in OOP terms, baseHp and getHp would be like private static members used by
    //the whole class.

    return function () {
        //another "private" variable, but this one is only for 
        //the current instance.
        var currentHp = baseHp * 100;

        //instance:
        return {
            name: "Mario",
            hp: function (value) {
                return !!value
                    ? currentHp = getHp(currentHp, value)
                    : getHp(currentHp);
            }
        };
    };
})();
```

I've tested this in the console, and it seems to work fine:

```
//test
var Enemy = {
    baseHp: 3
};
var log = console.log.bind(console);
var mario = Mario(); //or new Mario(); either one is fine
log(mario);
log(mario.hp());
log(mario.hp(-20));
log(mario.hp());
```

Try it out on jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jmorgan123/zkw2P/

Comment: Thanks Justint! This is helpful. Side Note: I was keeping baseHp public so that if I were to change it later, I could affect the hp of all instances of Mario.